# Introduction/tutorial for XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm looking for a good introduction/tutorial for XAML. The [Silverlight.Net Quickstarts](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/) are very good, but I was wondering what else is out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [site](http://www.wpftutorial.net/) has been good to me, though I feel the guy in the upper right is watching me the whole time.